# Display form fields according to the role of the user in Symfony2?

Tags: forms, symfony

How can I restrict the access to some fields for users in symfony2?

Comment: Please post the code relevant to the question. You can do so by editing your own question, and adding it there, in the body of the question. It will help us helping you.

Answer (score 1):

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html  - search for is_granted

In your twig template:

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}
    {{ form_row(form.somthingOnlyTheAdminGetsToSee) }}
{% endif %}
```

Keep in mind that it would be better to create role specific forms.  A hacker could still post the admin fields.